# ¿por qué mii página cargada con .load() en un div desaparece después de un get o post?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

soy un poco novato con JQuery y no he podido solucionar le siguiente problema.
Tengo un js de mi página principal, el cual carga una página en un div cuando dan click en una opción del menú; hasta ahí todo tranquilo, el problema viene cuando en la página que mando a llamar ejecuta un get o un post esta desaparece y se reinicia al index. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Dejo a continuación el código.

Query principal:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#verUsuarios").on("click",function(){
   $("#contenedor").load("VerUsuarios.jsp");
});
});
```

Query de VerUsuarios.jsp

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
$(".baja").on("click",function(){
   $.get("desactivateUser",{id:$(this).val()},function(){
   });
});

$(".alta").on("click",function(){
   $.post("activate",{id:$(this).val()},function(){
   });
});
}); `
```

En VerUsuarios.jsp tengo una tabla con un  que tiene de clase baja o clase alta y mando a llamar a un servlet que hace la operación de ir a la base de datos y cambiarle el estado al usuario.
Espero puedan ayudarme a solucionar este problema, gracias.

Comment: Intenta dejando `$("#verUsuarios").on("click",function(){
   $("#contenedor").load("VerUsuarios.jsp");
});` por fuera del document.ready.

Comment: Lo he intentado y no ha funcionado, sigue recargándose la pagina completa

Comment: Esta parte: `el problema viene cuando en la página que mando a llamar ejecuta un get o un post esta desaparece y se reinicia al index` creo que deberías [edit] tu pregunta para agregar mas código. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Debes usar [`preventDefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) para evitar que el formulario se envíe. Por ejemplo: **`$("#verUsuarios").on("click",function(event){   event.preventDefault(); //resto del código`**  En el caso de los otros, lo mismo: **`$(".baja").on("click",function(event){event.preventDefault(); //resto del código`**  Nótese que `function` recibe un parámetro `event`.